Why can a vector field defined only on a curve be evaluated its covariant derivative along the non-tangent direction of the curve?
I am reading the Riemannian geometry part of complex differential geometry by Fangyang Zheng. I have a problem when reading the definition of index form:

Let us discuss the index lemma and the second variation formula. Fix a unit speed geodesic $\gamma:[0, a] \rightarrow M$ and denote by $T$ its tangent field. Let $V(t)$ be a piecewise smooth vector field along $\gamma$, that is, $V$ is continuous, and there exists a subdivision $0=t_{0}<t_{1}<\cdots<t_{k}=a$ such that $V$ is smooth in each $\left[t_{i-1}, t_{i}\right]$, $1 \leq i \leq k$. Define the index of $V$ by
$$I(V)=\int_{0}^{a}\left\langle R(T,V)T-V^{\prime \prime}, V\right\rangle d t+\left.\left\langle\nabla_{V} V, T\right\rangle\right|_{0} ^{a}+\Delta(V),$$
where
$$\Delta(V)=\int_0^a\langle V',V\rangle'dt=\sum_{i=1}^k\langle V',V\rangle|_{t_{i-1}^+}^{t_i^-}.$$

In the second term of $I(V)$, I can't understand what $\nabla_V V$ is. In my opinion, since $V$ is defined only on $\gamma([0,a])$, $V$ can only be taken the covariant derivative along $T$, that is, only $\nabla_T V$ is well-defined. If not, I wouldn't understand what this covariant derivative really is. We don't have the values of $V$ outside $\gamma([0,a])$. Any help would be appreciated!

I think you are right and that term should be $\langle\nabla_TV,V\rangle$. See proposition 10.24 in John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifolds (second edition).
